# Get correct height for a Div in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Please refer to pic below. I need to have the height value shown in the center box in the IE Developer Tools Layout window (893.79). I have tried an assortment of ways to obtain this value without success.  IE continues to give me the value 473.  I have tried ...`getElementByID('navigation').offsetHeight`, `clientHeight`, `scrollHeight`.  I have tried jquery's `.innerHeight(true)` and `outerHeight(true)`.
Any ideas?  Thank you for your time.

[image]

OK. Hope I don't confuse the situation with this.  Here is my HTML:

```html
A <div> at the top of the page:
<div id="yui-main" set-height> ==> set-height is my directive
.....
.....
<div id="navigation" class="yui-b" ng-controller="commonController" >  
 ==> class="yui-b" has the following css values: width: 23em; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;
    <div id="InfoByTopic"> ==> has the following css: a url pointing to a jpg for background; padding-bottom: 2px
 .........
    </div>
    
    <div id = "InfoByState">  ==> has the following css values: margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: content-box;
        <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resource/state" method="POST">
  .......
        </form>
    </div>

    <h2 class="invisible">Some Info Here</h2>
    <ul id="hotxxx"> ==> has the following css values: a url pointing to a jpg for background; padding-bottom: 2px;
       margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 .75em;
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.xxxxx.net" title='blah blah'><font color="#0000CC"><span>Some Stuff Here</span></font></a>SOME NONSENSE HERE</li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.YYYY.aspx" title='blah blah'><font color="#0000CC"><span>More Stuff Here</span></font></a>MORE NONSENSE HERE</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my angular directive where I get the height of the 'navigation' div:

```js
    myApp.directive('setHeight', function($window){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',

            link: function(scope, element, attrs){

                angular.element(document).ready(function() {

                    console.log( "navigation div height: " + document.getElementById('navigation').offsetHeight);
     ==>in IE Dev Tools Console:  "navigation div height: 472"
     ==>in Chrome Console: "navigation div height: 891"
     

                });

            }
        }
    })
```

Notice the value being returned by IE (11) vs Chrome?  FF returns a value of 895.

Comment: BTW:  Chrome and FF are returning the value 891, which is good enough.

Comment: post your code so we can reproduce. http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Posted code.  Don't know if I did it the correct way.  Apologies if I posted the addendum's incorrectly.